# Alternating vibration motor

Tags: 555, motor-controller, vibration-motor

I would like to build a circuit similar to the two alternating flashing lights circuit, but using two disc vibration motors instead. I’d like it to have a speed control. The vibration motors have 30ohm resistance and my voltage is 4xAA batteries (~6V). When I set this up with a 555 timer based on schematics for flashing lights both motors run continuously rather than alternating. Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: Use the 555 to drive a power transistor to drive the motor. The 555 can't put out enough current from its pins to drive the motor. And why do you say alternating in your title? There is no alternating in your post body.

Comment: Use the built-in schematic editor to show us what you built. Also, provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the vibration motors.

Comment: That is 2 separate circuits. Variable PWM V to motor and variable V low F inverter clock with bidirectional current to two LEDs alternating 0 to say 10 Hz, While DC motor might go to 11,000 RPM @ 5V or 167 HZ Thus the motor see variable duty cycle high F and LEDs see variable low f increasing with PWM duty cycle.   Hmmm

Comment: Or do you want to pulse motor from 0 to 10Hz with 0.05s burst and then at 20Hz it is constant 5~6V DC. Then you have 2 ccts. A one shot and a pot control pulser from 0 to 20 Hz to get max speed but meanwhile motor is 167 Hz (?)

Comment: what schematics are you talking about?

Comment: "*I set this up with a 555 timer based on schematics for ...*" Can you provide links for the schematics in the question. You can [edit] it into the question.